# OCaml map on a tuple

Tags: ocaml

I have several places in my code which look like this:

```
let (a,b,c) = (f "a", f "b", f "c")
```

It would be nice if I can write something like:

```
let (a,b,c) = map f ("a", "b", "c")
```

If there is way to do something like this in OCaml?

Comment: Will your `a`, `b` and `c` always have the same type?  Is your `f` always intended to be distributable over an ordered triple of the same type?

Comment: OCaml's type system doesn't support arrays of a specific length or homogenous tuples parametrized by their length. If we had those, one could then have a single map function of type `('a -> 'b) -> ('a, <n>) array -> ('b, <n>) array`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily write `map` for triples of one type of element:

```
let map_triple f (a, b, c) = (f a, f b, f c)

let a, b, c = map_triple String.length ("foo", "bar", "quux")
```

It will only work for one length of tuple, however.

It would be possible to write a GADTified tuple type and write a `map` over that type that is polymorphic in the length of the tuple, but that kind of trickery is best avoided unless the advantage is large, which does not seem to be the case here.

Answer (score 6):

The best answer is that you can't do this, if you want it to work for tuples of different sizes. Each tuple size is a different type in OCaml. So there's no OCaml type representing the idea of "a tuple of any size whose elements are strings."

But in fact this sounds like a list more than a tuple. If you can use lists instead of tuples, you can use the plain old `List.map` function.

Comment: I do not mind using List.map but I wan to be able to easily bind results to variables:

Comment: You can easily write a function for each size of tuple: `let mapt3 f (a, b, c) = (f a, f b, f c)`. If you have only a few sizes this might be a decent solution.